# PopupMenu in Android 2.1 API 7

Tags: android

I am developing **Android 2.1 API 7** app. I am also using [ActionbarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library to implement **Action Bar**.

Now, I need to implement `PopupMenu` which is only support by API 11+.

How can I implement `PopupMenu` in Android 2.1 API 7 ?

Comment: Please check this pre-asked question: [Appropriate alternative to PopupMenu for pre-Honeycomb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878916/appropriate-alternative-to-popupmenu-for-pre-honeycomb) It'll help you over the concept.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621070/get-context-of-popupmenu-like-contextmenu

Comment: What about using [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere)?

Answer (score 4):

use the Android Support V7 Library;
     `android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu`

Answer (score 1):

I'v stucked with such a problem, and the only solution i'v found for myself was to use a list dialog in android sdk<11 and ListPopup in android 11 and higher.

Comment: This is the solution I've settled for in the end, even after discovering solutions like HoloEverywhere which would theoretically allow PopupMenus in earlier API versions. It's just so much less overhead!

Answer (score 1):

you can use [HoloEveryWhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere), it bringing Holo theme from android 4.1 to 2.1 and above.

Comment: In case it helps anybody else: I tried the HoloEverywhere route. It's a bit of a sledgehammer approach, with fairly big setup costs and size overhead in your binary. You might want to consider if you really need a PopupMenu at all in API v7, whether you could use a ListViewActivity or somesuch instead.

Answer (score 0):

Its Possible Import That Particular API files in your code , I think eclipse will do it for you , Just write code and if not imported than google it to import API.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ListDialogFragment which extends the SherlockDialogFragment and create your own Listener interface so you can handle selection events.

```
public class ListDialogFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment {

private String[] mValues;

public interface ListDialogListener {
    void onFinishListDialog(int selectedIndex, String tag);
}

private ListDialogFragment(String[] values) {
    mValues = values;
}

public static ListDialogFragment newInstance(int index, String[] values) {
    ListDialogFragment fragment = new ListDialogFragment(values);

    // Supply index input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("index", index);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}

public int getSelectedIndex() {
    return getArguments().getInt("index", 0);
}

}
```