# Phones with API >= 11?

Tags: java, android

I'm planning to use the pop up menu API.  However it is only for API 11 and above.  I don't want to use it if there are still a significant number of phones out there with API<11. However I have no idea of the current state of API levels on android phones.   Would it be safe to say that the majority of phones out there can use this or can update to it?

Comment: By pop menu do you mean the three dots at the end of the action bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what is this "popup menu", but you can simply set the minSdk to 11 in the manifest if you want to support only devices that have API 11 and above :

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Also, for statistics of the Android about the API number, check [this website](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) . Currently, a little less than 50% of the android devices run on API 11 and above.

I would recommend to try to make your app run on older devices, at least from API 8 or 9. There are many compatibility libraries out there that could help you.

Comment: actually it was "popup menu" not "pop menu". I'm not sure how adding the minSdk in the manifest is relevant and will make it work on phones with < API 11, but besides that you answered my question exactly like i wanted.  Thanks

Comment: OK, i've updated my answer, and I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: About the PopupMenu, I think I know what you mean. There are alternatives for this, for example: www.github.com/u1aryz/android-newpopupmenu , www.github.com/lorensiuswlt/newquickaction , www.github.com/lorensiuswlt/newquickaction3d

Answer (score 0):

1. According to http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html, there are currently 44% of devices on the Android market that have Gingerbread r2 (API level 10). So no, it does not look like you can rely on the API level being higher than 11.
2. You could search whether another library, be it Google's [Android support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) or a third party one, like e.g. [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/), has the support for the API you want. However, it seems neither of these two implements [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html).
3. It looks like, according to other Stack Overflow answers ([Appropriate alternative to PopupMenu for pre-Honeycomb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878916/appropriate-alternative-to-popupmenu-for-pre-honeycomb) and [PopupMenu in Android 2.1 API 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275228/popupmenu-in-android-2-1-api-7)), that PopupMenu was not designed for small phone screens in mind.

Comment: There are Android tablets with API<11.  The original galaxy Tab was 2.3, and I worked on a 7 inch Dell model in the 2.2 or 2.3 days.  Had the pre-release model on my desk.  There's very few tablets that old, but not zero.

Comment: @GabeSechan: Oh you are right I had forgotten these.